# Can't Login with spring security rest and angualrjs

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot, csrf-protection

i am stuck in rest spring security and AngularJS my spring boot parent version is 1.3.3.RELEASE. my problem is when i send authentication request to spring security on **"/login"** spring security return below response.

```
{"timestamp":1420467113764,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?","path":"/login"}
```

Below i will show you my response and configuration file of spring security and services in AngularJS.

**Spring Security Configuration File**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SpringSecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetail userDetail;

@Autowired
private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
@Autowired
private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;
@Autowired
private AuthSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;


/**
 * Configuration of Spring Security
 */

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


    http
        .logout().invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .and().addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class).csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());


    http
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/register.do","/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/home/**").access("hasRole('Admin')")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
    http
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);

}

private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
    return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                    .getName());

            if (csrf != null) {
                Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                String token = csrf.getToken();
                if (cookie == null || token != null
                        && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                    cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                    cookie.setPath("/");
                    response.addCookie(cookie);

                }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    };
}

private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
      HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
      repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
      return repository;
    }

/**
 * To Ignore Spring MVC Resources
 */

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**");
}
/**
 * Authenticate User with Credential
 * @param auth
 * @throws Exception
 */

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    /*Below code is for use spring security without datasoruce*/

    /*auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .withUser("abc@gmail.com").password("abc").roles("Admin");*/

    /*Below code is for use spring security with datasoruce*/

    auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetail).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

/**
 * Password Encoder 
 * @return
 */

@Bean
public PlaintextPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new PlaintextPasswordEncoder();
}
```

}

**RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint**

```
@Component
public class RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
        throws IOException, ServletException {


    ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JSONResponse<HashMap<String, Object>> jsonResponse = new JSONResponse<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    jsonResponse.setStatus(Constants.ERROR);
    jsonResponse.setMessage(Constants.INVALID_CREDENTIAL);

    response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.print(jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonResponse));
    }
}
```

**RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler**

```
@Component
public class RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {


    ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JSONResponse<HashMap<String, Object>> jsonResponse = new JSONResponse<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    jsonResponse.setStatus(Constants.ERROR);
    jsonResponse.setMessage(Constants.INVALID_CREDENTIAL);

    response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.print(jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonResponse));


    }
}
```

**AuthSuccessHandler**

```
@Component
public class AuthSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

    JSONResponse<HashMap<String, Object>> jsonResponse = new JSONResponse<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Users users = userService.getByEmail(authentication.getName());

    if (users != null) {
        jsonResponse.setStatus(Constants.SUCCESS);
        jsonResponse.setMessage(Constants.SUCCESS_CREDENTIAL);
        HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        data.put("id", users.getUserId());
        jsonResponse.setData(data);
    }


    response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.print(jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonResponse));
    }
}
```

**SimpleCORSFilter**

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "x-auth-token, x-requested-with,Content-Type, Accept,X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

}

public void destroy() {
}

}
```

**Angular Controller**

```
vm.login=function(){

    userServices.login(vm.data).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            vm.getUser();
        },
        function(response) {
            if(response.status=== 403){
                console.log($cookies["XSRF-TOKEN"]);
                $http.defaults.headers.post['X-XSRF-TOKEN']=$cookies["XSRF-TOKEN"];
                vm.login();

            }

        });
}
```

**Angular Factory**

```
app.factory('userServices', ['$http','root',function($http,root) {
  return {
    login : function(data,header) {
        return $http.post(root+"login",$.param({'username':data.email,'password':data.password}),{headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}});
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: I think you should use `.csrf().disable()` on logout

Comment: thank you but still is not working @ojuskulkarni

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: same error which i was given. have you any tutorial for that ? @ojuskulkarni

Comment: go through spring documentation, it has good explanation

Comment: Ohks np i will try @ojuskulkarni